# MultiTouch HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-touch

I would like to know if it is possible for MultiTouch to be implemented on HTML.

Scenario like this:

```html
<iframe id="Example1"
    src="examplescroller.htm">
</iframe>
<iframe id="Example2"
    src="examplescroller.htm">
</iframe>
```

Two iframe are been used, two of them have page scroller. If two finger were used to scroll the page, both of them should work simultaneously.

I have read up on Canvas (touchstart, touchmove amd touchend) but it doesn't support iframes and I have also search for various Javascript Multitouch but they are usually used for drawing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 certainly supports multi-touch, and theres a great article [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/) that details it quite well, nothing about iframe's though. Multi-touch is possible though. You didn't actually state if your current code works for you or not, but I assume it doesn't. I would look into multitouch exclusively more rather than how it works with iframes, and see if you can adapt it to them.

Comment: I have read up on the link you have shared. However, I'm not too sure how the control touches work. Similar with the link [here](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/html5-mobile-web-touch-). I would probably need a snippet of a code that would actually make a div/iframe multi-touchable, as previously  mention, most of it uses canvas which is towards drawing instead of allowing certain area to be MultiTouch.